# Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma Algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, gt.game-theory

While reading a post on Scott Aaronson's blog about Eigenmorality, I ran across the idea of the iterated prisoner's dilemma tournament.  I've studied some TCS on my own, but had never really thought carefully about algorithms for an IPD.

I subsequently read that the generally-acknowledged "best strategy" for winning IPD games is the tit-for-tat strategy, but that there are some possible improvements.  My question is, given an IPD tournament, is there a sort of "evolutionarily stable" bot that always wins against "mutant bots"--that is, an algorithm that will always defeat every other algorithm at IPD?  If so, what is it, and can its dominance over all other bots be proved?  If not, can this be proved?  (Is there a better question I should ask, such as, "If you assume that you are pitted against 5 million other randomly selected bots, which bot should you choose?")

My question may be too vague to be answered precisely, so if you could point me in the direction of relevant references, that would be just as helpful as a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no algorithm that always beats all others in an IPD tournament.  Proof: if your algorithm cooperates in round 1, then it gets last place in a tournament where all other bots always defect; if your algorithm defects in round 1, then it gets last place in a tournament where all other bots play unforgiving tit-for-tat (cooperate until the opponent defects, then defect forever).

If there are a finite number of rounds in each face-off of an IPD tournament, the sole Nash Equilibrium - [evolutionarily stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy) or otherwise - is that all bots always defect.  If instead each face-off has a constant probability of ending after each round (for example), then there might be many evolutionarily stable NEs, depending on how the payoff structure is organized.  One such ESNE is that all bots play tit-for-tat.

Evolutionary Stability is a pretty important game theory concept, though, and it sounds like that's the magic phrase you want to google.  My back-of-the-envelope intuition for it is this: a ball rolling along $f(x) = x^3$ is unlikely to come to a rest at $x = 0$, even though the first derivative is zero.  Nash Equilibrium is a first-order equilibrium concept that lists $x=0$ as an equilibrium of this system, but Evolutionary Stability is a second-order equilibrium concept that throws out $x = 0$ because if you poke the system, the equilibrium breaks.